# How to install phpMyAdmin to CentOS

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos6, yum

I am working on installing and configuring phpMyAdmin at work and I am having issue with my repo not finding all the dependences of phpMyAdmin. Below is my yum.repos.d list:

```
yum.repos.d]# ls
epel.repo  redhat.repo      remi-php71.repo  remi-safe.repo  zabbix.repo
notused    remi-php70.repo  remi.repo  temp
```

I run yum clean all command and I got this:

```
# yum clean all
Cleaning repos: epel remi-safe zabbix zabbix-non-supported
Cleaning up Everything
```

I also run yum repolist and here is the output:

```
# yum repolist
epel/metalink                                             |  13 kB     00:00
epel                                                      | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                           | 5.9 MB     00:00
remi-safe                                                 | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-safe/primary_db                                      | 436 kB     00:01
zabbix                                                    |  951 B     00:00
zabbix/primary                                            | 4.0 kB     00:00
zabbix                                                                     22/22
zabbix-non-supported                                      |  951 B     00:00
zabbix-non-supported/primary                              | 3.8 kB     00:00
zabbix-non-supported                                                       15/15
repo id              repo name                                             status
epel                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64        12,168
remi-safe            Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x  1,013
zabbix               Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64                       22
zabbix-non-supported Zabbix Official Repository non-supported - x86_64         15
repolist: 13,218
```

And below is the error message from #yum install phpMyAdmin, output below:

```
# yum install phpMyAdmin
Setting up Install Process
zabbix                                                    |  951 B     00:00
zabbix-non-supported                                      |  951 B     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.0.10.17-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mcrypt >= 5.2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.17-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.17-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.17-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.17-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-php-gettext for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.17-2.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-12.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el6.noarch
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch
---> Package php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.0.10.17-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.17-2.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-9.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-12.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el6.noarch
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.0.10.17-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.17-2.el6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.17-2.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-mbstring >= 5.2.0
Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-tidy
Error: Package: php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-posix
Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-bcmath
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Where do you think could be the problem and what can I do to address it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have base and updates standard repositories (provided by centos-release).

You also have "remi-safe" repository configured, PHP stack is also available in "remi-php56", "remiphp70" or "remi-php71" (not enabled repositories), but this also won't work without "base" repository.

phpMyAdmin 4.0 in EPEL is designed to work with PHP 5.3 in base repository.

Latest phpMyAdmin (4.6) is also in "remi" repository (not enabled, better if you want a recent PHP version), but again will need "base".